# Find out if HTC phone enters a mobile app

Tags: javascript, c#, mobile, user-agent

I know that this code will redirect for blackberries;

```
if ((/blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
        //Send to mobile page (Blackberries)
        window.location = ("../Default.aspx");
 }
```

But what would I use to replace `blackberry` for HTC phones?

I looked [here](http://www.cubrowsers.com/moviles/htc/) but there seems to be different ones for just about every phone. Is there a single call that I could use?

**Edit** A C# way to detect would work too. Something along the lines of this:

```
if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null && (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true"){
                if(Request.Browser ["BlackBerry"] == "true")
                {
                    if(int.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) < 4.5)
                    {
                       //This is how you get blackberry version right?
                    }

                }
                else if(Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("HTC"))
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try **HTC** b/c it seems that every mozilla useragent on HTC has HTC a/c to you provided link.

Comment: Why would you do the redirection on the clientside and not the server? Yuck!

Comment: Yea, I may switch back to server side. There are too many options (blackberry versions, htc, ect) to do is server side anymore

Comment: @Asad Rasheed - Make that an answer `if(Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("HTC")){//Code}` picks up HTC phones

Comment: @Peppered Lemons: I just give you an idea from the link you posted, you implement it so I would suggest you to post the answer and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if a phone is an HTC server side do this:

```
if(Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("HTC")){
   //Code
}
```